# Can I call other contract function in constructor() in solidity?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Elevator {
  function goTo(uint) public {}
}

contract Counter {

    bool toggle = false;

    function isLastFloor(uint) external returns (bool) {
        if(toggle){
            return true;
        }
        toggle = true;
        return false;
    }

    constructor() public {
        Elevator(0xcBD906e7ba459CfC36D3e7591F50faa49763BC8E).goTo(3);
    }
}
```

This is my sample code. And this code isn't deployed via foundry.

[image]

Is there way call other contract functin in constructor()?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax inside the constructor is correct.

Assuming that the `Elevator` contract is deployed on address `0xcBD9...`, the `constructor` within `Counter` calls `Elevator`'s function `goTo()`.

If there's no contract on the `0xcBD9...` address, then the call fails, effectively reverting the `Counter` deployment.

Also, `data: None` in the error message suggests that your code might be trying to send a transaction to a contract address without specifying what function to execute. Which would revert because your contracts don't implement the `fallback()` nor `receive()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#special-functions).

---

The `goTo()` function that you shared in the question is empty. But based on the names of your functions, it seems that is related to Ethernaut level 11.

In the Ethernaut challenge, the `goTo()` function is not empty - and might revert for example because of an infinite recursion. :)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Why my code cause infinite recursion? My code is deployed -> call constructor() -> call Elevator(0xcBD9...).goTo() and function goTo() is never call any function. So I can't understand.

Comment: @chobo Your code doesn't cause infinite recursion as it's currently written... My point was that the naming suggests Ethernaut challenge, where the code is slightly different (but with the same function names). And this Ethernaut code causes infinite recursion (not yours).